# How to look for sentences having single characters using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, arabic

I'm trying to print out sentences from a dataframe that contains words with one character no matter where it is beginning of the sentence middle or end of it, the challenge is my code works perfectly for English script but when I change the scrips say to Arabic it prints wrong output all sentences instead of the wanted output that has one letters in it.

```
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(tdata.count(' ') == 0)
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)
df = tdata[dftdata'sentences'].str.contains(r'\b\w{1}\b')]
print(df)


a sample set
-----------------------------

#هلو كيفك م هي اخباركم
#ج ليش اتاخرت اليوم
#هو كلش نذل
#ترا اني كلش حباب ذ
#باب المدرسة ب مفتوح
#الحمدالله الكل بخير
#كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا نعتمد على والدنا في مصروفنا
#كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا لا تعرف كيفَ نتحدث بطريقة لائقة في المجلس
#كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا لا نعرف كيفَ نعبر الشارِع بمفردنا
#هل اهتممتم بوالدتكم  انها مسكينة قد لاحظت انها متعبة جداً ً
#كفاكُن كلام اذهبن  ادرسن َ  اجتهدن
#لِمَ لا تجففن مستحضر (طين البحر الميت ) قبل أن تستخدمنه ُ  
#  ادرسن َ  
# أعشقك ِ
#هل   ً
-----------------------------

expected output 

-----------------------------
#هلو كيفك م هي اخباركم
#ج ليش اتاخرت اليوم
#ترا اني كلش حباب ذ
#باب المدرسة ب مفتوح
-----------------------------
```

Why this code does not work for Arabic script same as English one ?

I also tried another method which did not work

```
tdata.loc[tdaTa.sentences.str.contains(r"([^\w]|^)\w([^\w]|$)")]
```

cant we create an array of the letters we want like ( ذ ب ا م ك خ ح ) and when they come alone in a sentence print that sentence wont that be a much better way and less headache ?

Comment: @jezreal any ideas bro ? I put some examples aswell to find the letters such as **م** **ج** **ذ** **ب**

Comment: Does `df[df['sentences'].str.split().map(lambda x: any(len(y) == 1 for y in x))]` do what you want?

Comment: @cs95 well not completely the output s better but still finds other sentences that does not have single character letters

Comment: cant we create an array of the letters we want like ( ذ ب ا م ك خ ح ) and when they come alone in a sentence print that sentence wont that be a much better way and less headache ? is that doable @cs95

Comment: becasue your code returns back anything even symbols like brackets ( { if there is no letters attached to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# mocking the dataframe based on your sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences': [
    'هلو كيفك م هي اخباركم',
    'ج ليش اتاخرت اليوم',
    'هو كلش نذل',
    'ترا اني كلش حباب ذ',
    'باب المدرسة ب مفتوح',
    'الحمدالله الكل بخير',
    'كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا نعتمد على والدنا في مصروفنا',
    'كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا لا تعرف كيفَ نتحدث بطريقة لائقة في المجلس',
    'كم نَحنُ كبار  مع هذا لا نعرف كيفَ نعبر الشارِع بمفردنا',
    'لِمَ لا تجففن مستحضر (طين البحر الميت ) قبل أن تستخدمنه'
]})

# selecting sentences with a single Arabic character word using regex
pattern = '(?<![\u0600-\u06ff])[\u0600-\u06ff](?![\u0600-\u06ff])'
df = df[df['sentences'].str.contains(pattern)]

print(df)
#                sentences
# 0  هلو كيفك م هي اخباركم
# 1     ج ليش اتاخرت اليوم
# 3     ترا اني كلش حباب ذ
# 4    باب المدرسة ب مفتوح
```

**Regex Explanation**:

```py
pattern = '(?<![\u0600-\u06ff])[\u0600-\u06ff](?![\u0600-\u06ff])'
```

`[\u0600-\u06ff]` is covering the standard Arabic [unicode range](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) including letters, numbers, and diacritics. Using negative lookbehind `(?<![\u0600-\u06ff])` and negative lookahead `(?![\u0600-\u06ff])` we limit the match to any single Arabic character that neither preceded nor followed by another Arabic character.

In case you want match a specific set of characters and not all of them, change the middle `[\u0600-\u06ff]` to any set you want. For example, if you want to match only Arabic digits from zero to nine, then use `[\u0660-\u0669]` instead:

```py
pattern = '(?<![\u0600-\u06ff])[\u0660-\u0669](?![\u0600-\u06ff])'
```

For english, the whole pattern should be like:

```py
pattern = '\b\w\b'
```

Comment: Can you explain what does **\b\w\b** do please ?

Comment: It does the same as `\b\w{1}\b` but I removed `{1}` because it's redundant here.

Comment: Added regex explanation to the answer

Comment: I don't understand this code for some reasons does not work fully  with Arabic sentences it still prints other sentences for me from my original dataset

Comment: I updated the answer and working on a solution for new sentences you add which have Arabic diacritics making the other problem

Comment: the sentences might contain something like that as well which is wrong to give as an output لِمَ لا تجففن مستحضر (طين البحر الميت ) قبل أن تستخدمنه ُ

Comment: the output here is much much better for my data set what if I want to define what single letters to find like just find (ذ ب ا م ة ) shall where shall I change in the code ?

Comment: like in your case you put a range for all the arabic letters what if I want to specify the letters rather than putting the whole range in @dralshehri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207487/discussion-between-programming-freak-and-dralshehri).

Comment: I wrote something in the chat if you can follow up and help man